# Slideshow to drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have come across a small issue that I'm dealing with at the moment.

I'm wanting to convert a carousel file slider into a plain two column menu.

**Here is the current template:**

[image]

**Here is what I would like it to look like:**

[image]

Here is the Javascript code:

```js
function getOneDriveFiles(){
 //PnP call here

 $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "BASE URL"
 });

 $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("FOLDER TO GRAB FILES").files.orderBy("Name").get().then(function(f){
  console.log(f);

  var files = '';

  $.each(f, function(index, value){
   var filesHtml = "<div class='file'>" + 
       "<a href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "'><img  src='IMAGE URL' /></a>" + 
       "<a href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "'><p id='fileTitle'>" + value.Name + "</p></a>" + 
       "</div></div>";
   
   files = files + filesHtml;
  });

  $(".files").append(files);

  /*$('.files').slick({
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   speed: 300,
   slidesToShow: 5,
   slidesToScroll: 5,
   prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='//fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/prev_new.png'>",
      nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='//fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/next_new.png'>",
   responsive: [
   {
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
    }
   },
   {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
    }
   },
   {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
    }
   }
   ]
  });*/
 });
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="files">
  /*    Blank   */
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/apps/O365-Slider/o365FileSlide.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you checked that `files` is a valid html string? At first glance you seem to be adding a '</div>' too many for each file.

Comment: Yes it is, it's linked back to another file in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `rows` setting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getAndAddFiles();

  $("#slider").slick({
    rows: 2,
    slidesPerRow: 2
  });
});

function getAndAddFiles() {
  var files = ['1.docx', '2.docx', '3.docx', '4.docx', '5.docx', '6.docx', '7.docx', '8.docx'];

  files.forEach(function(e) {
    $('#slider').append('<div class="file"><div class="inner">' + e + '</div></div>');
  });
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper #slider {
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper #slider .file .inner {
  background-color: #13f1fc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```